# Diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#Ejemplo lista con diccionarios
#'''
contactos = [{"contacto":"Abel", "id":"a-21440"},{"email":"emailgoogle@gmail.com"}]
print(contactos)
print(contactos[1]["email"])
print("--------------------")
print("Listado de contactos")
for x in contactos:
    print(f"Nombre del contacto:{x['contacto']}")
#'''
```

No sé q estoy hacinedo mal que siempre me marca este error en consola. Todo está bien hasta llegar a la linea 35, donde hay error q no logro identificar. Parece q no reconoce el indice pero claramente "contacto" existe en el diccionario.

```
Listado de contactos
Nombre del contacto:Abel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Listas y Arreglos\02Sets_y_Diccionarios.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(f"Nombre del contacto:{x['contacto']}")
KeyError: 'contacto'
```

Comment: Al iterar por la lista `contactos`, en cada iteración `x` será uno de sus elementos, que son diferentes diccionarios cada vez. El primer diccionario tiene los campos "contacto" e "id". El segundo en cambio solo tiene el campo "email". Es al llegar al segundo que te da el error, pues intentas acceder a `x["contacto"]`

Comment: ¿no será que todos los datos del contacto, es decir, su nombre, id y email, deberían estar juntos en un solo diccionario, en vez de separarlo en dos como lo tienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tu error está en el bucle**

Dados estos dos elementos

```py
[{"contacto":"Abel", "id":"a-21440"},{"email":"emailgoogle@gmail.com"}]
```

Al iterar sobre el diccionario, ten en cuenta que el segundo elemento no tiene `contacto`, por lo que es mejor comprobar si `x` tiene `contacto` con `in`

```py
if "contacto" in x
```

**Solución**

```py
#Ejemplo lista con diccionarios
#'''
contactos = [{"contacto":"Abel", "id":"a-21440"},{"email":"emailgoogle@gmail.com"}]
print(contactos)
print(contactos[1]["email"])
print("--------------------")
print("Listado de contactos")
for x in contactos:
    if "contacto" in x:
        print("Nombre del contacto: "+x["contacto"])
#'''
```

**Salida esperada**

```py
[{'contacto': 'Abel', 'id': 'a-21440'}, {'email': 'emailgoogle@gmail.com'}]                                                   
emailgoogle@gmail.com                                                                                                         
--------------------                                                                                                          
Listado de contactos                                                                                                          
Nombre del contacto: Abel
```

Comment: Gracias. Aunque aun no encuentro como(si es q es posible) hacer q me muestre los nombres, si 'id' tambien se llamara 'contacto'